# spell check and singular/plural check in VB/Java/SQL

Tags: sql-server, search, vb6, spell-checking

Im basically trying to do a simple search utility in my SQL Server database.

Need to search for "different form of words" typed by the user including spell check, singular/plural. Having the present/past/future tense also considered will be a super-to-have feature.

Can you help me find API(s) for each of these or all in one. Im only looking for open Source or Freeware.

Language Im looking for is either VB or Java. Im kind of new to Java and I looked at Lucene and wasnt sure if it will help me.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [SQL Server Full-Text Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx)?

Comment: Its interesting! Im trying to see how to create/use this. Im running SQL Server 8.00.2039 - SP4 (Standard Edition) server. Kind of newbie to SQL Server, would help if you can provide some links, :)